Change to an input field in a JavaScript Datatable autochange the value of another field in the datatable?
I am working on a DOT Net MVC project. My Razor code has a datatable with input field Points and 2 other fields DaysAssigned and DaysRemaining. The value of DaysRemaining field changes according to this formula :
DaysRemaining = DaysAssigned - (Points /10)
My code is working for only the 1st row of the datatable. Changes to the Points field in any row of the datatable updates DaysRemaining field in the 1st row only.
Here is my code :
$('.Points').on("keyup", function() {
    var points = $(this).val().trim();  //get the value entered          
    var daysassign = $("#DaysAssigned").val().trim();                     
    let total = daysassign - (points / 10);
    $("#DaysRemaining").val(total);       
});

I am new to javascript. Will appreciate any help while I keep working on this issue.
Thanks,
I have tried to find the Row index of Points field in the datatable and to update the corresponding DaysRemaining field but have been unsuccessful. Maybe there is another solution out there I am not aware of.

The question implies that you're re-using id values in your HTML, which means your HTML is invalid.  id needs to be unique in the document.  Aside from that, I would suspect that DataTables has an API for modifying the data it uses?  It seems unlikely that you'd want to update the DOM directly and would instead want to update the backing data and let DataTables update its rendering.  (Assuming you're truly using DataTables?  The question isn't clear about that.  Please read the tag description for the datatable tag you're using, it's ambiguous.)

You probably want something like $(this).closest("tr").find(".DaysRemaining").val(total) so you update the field in the same row.

That works, Thank you Barmar!

you can also use like this:
var daysassign = $(this).closest("tr").find(".DaysAssigned").val().trim();
$(this).closest("tr").find(".DaysRemaining").val(total);

That is correct Nilesh, I will have to use $(this).closest("tr") for DaysAssigned field as well.
